# How do I resolve "Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH error"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

As a beginner in Visual Studio Editor, I am currently running into an error that says "Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH" when I try running a (Javascript) program.

I have tried many ways I can find such as editing the terminal or launch.json in some way, but they all don't work, lead to other errors or are possibly outdated.
Besides, the integrated terminal seems to be unable to respond.

I have installed Node.js, and I'd like to know how I can resolve this error.

Comment: I've read answers online about this suggesting to simply restart your PC for the node path to be recognised. If you haven't, I'd suggest trying that first.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once and I resolved it by adding node to my system environment variables.

on your system, search for the node application and copy the file location.
Then, in your windows explorer search for "environment variables",
Click "Edit system environment variables",
Click "Environment Variables" in the dialog.
In the "System Variables" box, search for Path and edit it to include the file location you copied.
Make sure it is separated from any other paths by a ;.